# How to call text from a function and print it on Tkinter GUI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

I have a scenario where I need to fetch some text and print it inside the Tkinter GUI canvas when a button is pressed.

The code inside the function looks as follows:

```
def plot_best_batsmen():
    print("The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be: ",
          dataset.loc[dataset.loc[dataset['Innings']>=15,'Average'].idxmax(),'Names'])
```

The code for the button is as follows:

```
b5 = Button(root, text="Best Batsmen", command=plot_best_batsmen, bg="#34495E", fg="white").pack(side = LEFT)
```

My expected result is to print the name of the player along with an image on the Tkinter GUI when the button is clicked. But when I run the code on Anaconda, it's printing the name on the console instead of printing inside the GUI.

Can anyone please help me in solving this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Use `canvas.create(x,y, text=' ' anchor='nw)` in the function. `Label()` can also be used.

I assume you have defined `Canvas` already before the function

**Here is an example.**

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

canvas = Canvas(root)
canvas.pack()

def plot_best_batsmen():
    text = "The best Batsman of the Tournament could possibly be: ", dataset.loc[dataset.loc[dataset['Innings']>=15,'Average'].idxmax(),'Names']
    canvas.create_text(1, 1, text=text, anchor='nw')

b5 = Button(root, text="Best Batsmen", command=plot_best_batsmen, bg="#34495E", fg="white")
b5.pack(side = LEFT)

mainloop()
```

Comment: I am getting the following error:
`SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument`

Comment: it might be from something else I ran the code and this works fine for me.

Comment: @Vivek My bad you were right, I fixed it now hope it works.